# how set select all option in multipart select option using knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

```
Html:

  <select name="item" id="item" class="input-fo" multiple="multiple" data-bind="
                                options         : categories,
                                optionsValue    : '_id',
                                optionsText     : 'name',
                                selectedOptions : selectedCategory,
                                select2         : {}
                            ">
 </select>
```

ViewModel:

```
     this.selectedCategory = ko.observable(1);
    this.selectedCategory.subscribe(function (options) {
         if(options.length >0){
            if (options.find('select_all')) {
                console.log("................INSIDE IF.............");
                       ***IF Select all option is true other option  selected deselect***
            }else{
                console.log("................INSIDE ELSE IF.............");

            }   
        } 
    });
```

Above is my code select multiple category from select option,Here i going to try Eduction dropdown in [Url](http://profile.bharatmatrimony.com/search/search.php?gaact=HP&gasrc=SRCHBHARAT).in that url when i select 'Any' in that education select option others unselect.So please any one give some idea for design that dropdown using Knockout js.

Comment: could you provide jsfiddle?