# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'selectedBases'

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Any Ideas what I'm doing wrong? because i get error message **Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'selectedBases'**  below is my code

```
this.selectedBases = ko.observable();
        this.selectedBases.subscribe(function (options) {
             if(options.length >0){
                if (options.find('select_all')) {
                    self.selectedBases(options.intersect('select_all'));
                } 
            } 
        });
```

Comment: where the `self` is defined?

Comment: in top of my code var self=this;

Comment: we need to see its definition too

Comment: After this statement `this.selectedBases = ko.observable();` this.selectedBases stores the returned value of `ko.observable()`. What exactly are you trying to do then?

Comment: Listen to value changes of course.

Comment: Plz see this url : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18584896/how-set-select-all-option-in-multipart-select-option-using-knockoutjs